# Eclipse no debug keystore

Tags: android, eclipse, keystore

I was trying to get the debug.keystore for using the Google map service on my Android application. I did some researches and found that the keystore will auto generated when i build the application, and the default location can be viewed in "Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK location".

But when i go to this folder, i can't see any debug.keystore, even i search on the spotlight, it shows there is no debug.keystore.

Is there any way to let eclipse to generate the debug.keystore again or find the existing keystore?

Comment: go to Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android -> build you will get default debug keystore as path like "/home/bhavesh/.android/debug.keystore"

Comment: By default it will be in the .android folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: you can find debug.keystore path from dev tool]

debugkeystore for window user it will be in users/.android dir

Comment: Thanks so much, i know what was my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Your default location is

```
C:\Users\accoutname\.android
```

you can use any location which you want ex.

```
C:\Key
```

if you want save here your keystore then follow this step

- Select File
- select Export then Export Android Application
- Project Browse
  selecte your Project
  Next Click
- Create new keystore select
- Browse your location
- give name.keystore
- give passwod
- click next